# ";" won't Repeat latest f,t,F or T in my vim

Tags: vim, macvim

I've learnt a new useful command ";" which can repeat latest f,t,F or T in document. However when I type ';', my vim do nothing.

here is my case

```
var foo = "method("+argument1+","+argument2+")";
```

1. I type "f+", the cursor then move to +
2. I type ";", the cursor doesn't move to next +

I suspect maybe ";" is map to other function. However when I type ":unmap ;", it shows message "No such mapping".

I don't know how to find the reason.

my environment:
macos, iterm2,
I've use vim config of https://github.com/chxuan/vimplus

Comment: does `:verbose map ;` show something? what happens if you start vim with `vim -u NONE` and try again?

Comment: when I do `:verbose map` it shows `No mapping found`. if I start vim with `vim -u NONE`, it work! it will move to next +. Is there anything wrong with my config?

Comment: it seems like it, your config or a plugin! `vim -u NONE` does start vim without plugins and config loaded. But it is a bit strange that there is no mapping overwriting it. I have currently no idea what it could be. But I would advise ditching vim plus and building your own config

Comment: thank you for your advice ~ According to your advice, I think there may be a plugin causing this problem. And I finally find a plugin called clever-f which caused this problem.I will accept your advice for building my own config.

Answer (score 1):

I have used a plugin called clever-f (https://github.com/rhysd/clever-f.vim) , clever-f.vim extends f, F, t and T mappings for more convenience. Instead of `;`, `f is available to repeat` after you type f{char} or F{char}.